# What is the best way to do historic comparisons of database data?

Tags: database-design, tracking

i have a database that has a list of employees of an organziation.  There is one main employee table and number of joined tables.

i want to start to track week over week and month over month metrics on this data so i can do things like:

**March 1: headcount 100 (+1, -2 in Feb)**
**April 1: headcount 101(+3, -2 in Mar)**
**May 1: headcount 105(+10, -6 in Apr)**

i am trying to thing of the best way to do this. do i:

1. Take a full database snapshot at the first of each month and have my application query multiple databases to generate these reports.
2. try to keep track of all changes in some db triggered history table and try to aggregate that information to try to build up current state of each month.
3. any other suggestions?

Comment: What platform?  For example, SQL Server 2008 has built-in change tracking.

Comment: SQL Server 2005 but if this is a solution for 2008 that does what i need above i would consider upgrading

Comment: I would recommend to elaborate on data size and what kind of queries you will want to run on the data - maybe that will spark some minds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to track when new employees are hired or terminated, then you should start with adding the relevant fields to the employee table itself: `HireDate date NOT NULL` and `TerminationDate date NULL`.

Then it's really quite easy to determine a headcount (and details) on any particular day:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, EmployeeName, ...
FROM Employees
WHERE HireDate <= @EndDate
AND (TerminationDate IS NULL OR TerminationDate > @BeginDate)
```

If you need to track *modifications* (i.e. a change in title), then the approach that will give you maximum flexibility is to maintain a real-time history table with triggers (or your database's built-in change tracking, if available).  I wouldn't recommend full snapshots as that will consume enormous amounts of space over the lifetime of the app.

Your history table should contain all of the fields in your base table, plus two more - a date modified and a transaction type.  Possibly a 3rd autonumber/sequence/identity field as well.  T-SQL version follows:

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeHistory
(
    TransactionID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1)
        CONSTRAINT PK_EmployeeHistory PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    TransactionDate datetime NOT NULL,
    TransactionType tinyint NOT NULL,    -- 1 = Add, 2 = Change, 3 = Delete
    EmployeeID int NOT NULL,
    EmployeeName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    ...
)
```

Then maintain it with a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Employees_History
ON Employees
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS BEGIN
    INSERT EmployeeHistory (TransactionDate, TransactionType, EmployeeID, ...)
        SELECT
            GETDATE(),
            CASE
                WHEN d.EmployeeID IS NULL THEN 1
                WHEN (i.TerminationDate IS NOT NULL) AND
                     (d.TerminationDate IS NULL) THEN 3
                ELSE 2
            END,
            i.EmployeeID, i.EmployeeName, ...
        FROM inserted i
        LEFT JOIN deleted d
        ON d.EmployeeID = i.EmployeeID
END
```

I'm going to assume you don't *delete* employee records and just set a `TerminationDate`; if you delete instead (please don't do this), then you'll need to write a similar `DELETE` trigger instead of the second `CASE WHEN i.TerminationDate ...` line.

Now seed your history table:

```
INSERT EmployeeHistory (TransactionDate, TransactionType, EmployeeID, ...)
    SELECT HireDate, 1, EmployeeID, ...
    FROM Employees
```

Note - if you don't have the `HireDate` then just replace that with `GETDATE()` - your history will only be valid from the moment you seed it.

Now if you want to get a historical "snapshot", you can do this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetEmployeeSnapshot(@ReportDate datetime)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
    WITH History_CTE AS
    (
        SELECT
            TransactionType, EmployeeID, EmployeeName, ...,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC) AS RowNum
            FROM EmployeeHistory
            WHERE TransactionDate <= @ReportDate
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM History_CTE
    WHERE RowNum = 1
    AND TransactionType IN (1, 2)    -- Filter out terminated employees
```

And if this query runs slow, if you need to speed up certain aggregates like a headcount, *then* and only then should you start thinking about snapshot tables:

```
CREATE TABLE HeadcountHistory
(
    ReportDate datetime NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_HeadcountHistory PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    HeadCount int NOT NULL
)
```

And the update proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateHeadcountHistory
AS

DECLARE @ReportDate datetime
SET @ReportDate = GETDATE()

INSERT HeadcountHistory (HeadCount)
    SELECT @ReportDate, COUNT(*)
    FROM dbo.GetEmployeeSnapshot(@ReportDate)
```

Run that last sproc as part of a scheduled job and then you'll have a denormalized reporting table for the specific aggregates you want.

Anything more complicated than this and I think you'd want to start looking into a data warehouse instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just running this on a schedule, then I would create a data summary table... once a month run a process to do your counts, and add a row to the summary table representing the data.  That way, you can look back into history and generate whatever statistics you need.  You might want to consider generating this data on a more frequent basis than you plan to report on (say, weekly)..   as long as you have higher resolution than the reporting period you should have all the data you need.

Comment: but if i wanted to drill down and view the details on a historic date, how could i "go back" and get the state at that time ?

Comment: if you want to know the details on a historic date then you don't have many options other than duplicating the appropriate columns into another table.  that would be a fairly unusual requirement, and I would question why you need that level of historical knowledge??